Remap Right Alt to Backspace
As the title says how can I remap Right Alt to Backspace?
I am on X11
I am aware that something can be done using setxkbmap but I not aware of the command for my particular case.

I am on NixOS btw so if I get the right command I can just add it to my configuration.nix to make it a permanent change

evremap can do that for you
git clone https://github.com/wez/evremap
nix-shell -p libevdev
cargo build --release


then follow the upstream config to rebind Right Alt to Backspace
